# Why won't this html page run, Devexpress documentation ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

http://chartjs.devexpress.com/Documentation/Tutorial/Configure_Charts?version=13_2

I am trying to make a ChartJS api implementation work however I just don't see what I am missing.

Here is the original page of instructions.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
      <!--script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.0.0.js"></script-->
      <!--script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="globalize.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="dx.chartjs.js"></script>

  <!-- ... -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  var chartDataSource = [
{
    year: 1950, Africa: 227, Americas: 331,
    Asia: 1436, Europe: 547, Oceania: 12
},
{
    year: 1960, Africa: 285, Americas: 416,
    Asia: 1718, Europe: 605, Oceania: 15
},
{
    year: 1970, Africa: 365, Americas: 512,
    Asia: 2156, Europe: 657, Oceania: 19
},
{
    year: 1980, Africa: 478, Americas: 612,
    Asia: 2644, Europe: 695, Oceania: 22
},
{
    year: 1990, Africa: 633, Americas: 720,
    Asia: 3180, Europe: 722, Oceania: 26
},
{
    year: 2000, Africa: 810, Americas: 833,
    Asia: 3678, Europe: 731, Oceania: 30
},
{
    year: 2010, Africa: 1016, Americas: 936,
    Asia: 4149, Europe: 728, Oceania: 35
}
];
    $(function () {
        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
dataSource: chartDataSource,
commonSeriesSettings: {
    argumentField: 'year'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Oceania',            
    valueField: 'Oceania'
}, {
    name: 'Africa',
    valueField: 'Africa'
},{
    name: 'Americas',
    valueField: 'Americas'
},{
    name: 'Asia',
    valueField: 'Asia'
},{ 
    name: 'Europe',
    valueField: 'Europe'
}]
});
      }

</script>



  </head>
  <body>

<div id="chartContainer" style="max-width:700px;height: 300px;"></div>


  </body>
```

Comment: Check all js files path is correct

Comment: Also internal scripts should be at the bottom of the body. Right above the </body> tag

Comment: yeap Internal script, Thank you

Comment: Did that solve you're issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed а closing bracket of your jQuery ready function. It is also not needed to place your internal script to the bottom of the body, as jQuery ready functions is used

So, here is [the working script](http://jsfiddle.net/eYq2p/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartDataSource = [ ... some data ... ];
    $(function () {
        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
            dataSource: chartDataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: 'year'
            },
            series: [{ name: 'Oceania', valueField: 'Oceania' }, 
                { name: 'Africa', valueField: 'Africa' },
                { name: 'Americas', valueField: 'Americas' },
                { name: 'Asia', valueField: 'Asia' },
                { name: 'Europe', valueField: 'Europe' }]
         });
    });
</script>
<div id="chartContainer" style="max-width:700px;height: 300px;"></div>
```